# Sort one column to match another in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet and I need to match the two columns together. However "Dove code" is 3600 rows and "code 2" is 1100. They all have the same codes as you can see in the image but you can also see where it starts changing and I need to have the codes all line up so I can see the gaps. I have already arranged them all alphabetically and its the "code 2" that would need to match up to "Dove code

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the above solution would result in too much shunting and vba is not an option, there's another way. Copy the first column and use 'remove duplicates' on it. Now you have an index list, put numbers from 1 to x in the column on the right of it.

Insert a column between the two lists and right of the second one.

Assuming that the index list is in F and the numbers in G, put this formula in the cell right of the first cell in the larger list:
 =VLOOKUP(A2,$F$2:$G$500,2,FALSE)

Adjust the range accordingly. Put the same formula in the cell right of the first cell in the shorter list, with of course C2 instead of A2. Copy both formules to the end of the list.

Now both columns have an index on every row. You can match them using data sort, but for that you need to add dummies in the index columns.

Put this formula in the cell right of your basic index list: =countif(B:B,G2)
And this one in the cell right of that: =countif(D:D,G2)

Now you know how many times each record arises in both lists. Just add extra numbers manually so that both formulas turn up the same result. You should be able to do that really fast. If you have 200 records that are used 2 times in the first column and not in the second one, just copy the index of those 200 records and paste them twice. The countif's will automatically update.
You can use an extra column to calculate the difference between the two counts and use data sort on your basic index list to sort on the diferences.

After that just use data sort.

IF my directions are clear enough, this shouldn't cost you more than 10 minutes.

Edit:
Here's an example: http://img14.imageshack.us/img14/6366/k8pg.jpg

Comment: Out of curiousty how is VBA not an option? Is it easier as I have no idea about it.

Comment: VBA is definitely an option. But I figured it wasn't on the table because there was no vba-tag (there is now).
A macro can do this really fast, but before you can use it, you have to think how to code it, code it, test it and then run it. By the time the macro works, you could've done my solution two times, if not more.

Answer (score 0):

Without VBA I do this (for columns with a limited number of mismatches!) by adding a formula such as `=INDIRECT("A"&ROW())<>INDIRECT("B"&ROW())` in a helper column. Working downwards, every time you see a TRUE shunt the appropriate column down to suit. But it may be only just about viable for 1100 rows!